# How to reference SVG file in Plotly Dash using dash-svg

Tags: python, svg, plotly-dash

I'm trying to reference a local image from my assets folder and display it as part of a Dash page header. Code is similar to this:

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State, callback
from dash_svg import Svg, Image

html.Nav(
    children=[
        html.H6('Page Title'),
        Svg(children=[
                Image(children='assets/my_svg.svg', height="2rem", width="auto")],
            viewBox='0 0 10 7')
    ]
)
```

I've read through the "documentation" (really just the JS files) here [dash-svg reference](https://github.com/stevej2608/dash-svg/blob/master/src/lib/components/Svg.react.js) and the Mozilla reference here [Mozilla  tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) (since the `dash-svg` developer describes the package as a "light wrapper" that's automatically scraped from Mozilla's site) but there doesn't seem to be any way to reference the file directly in either the `Svg` or `Image` objects like you would in straight HTML with the `href` tag e.g. `<image href="assets/my_svg.svg" height="2rem", width="auto"/>`

All I get is an empty frame roughly the size of the image I described... but no image. The HTML elements show up when you inspect it though. Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Class `html.Img` handles `svg` files as well. `dash_svg.Svg` is more about construction of such file, possibly dynamically.

##### SVG file

```py
from dash import html

html.Img(
    src='assets/my_svg.svg',
    style={'height': '2em', 'width': 'auto'}),
```

rendered as:

```html
<img src="assets/my_svg.svg" style="height: 2em; width: auto;">
```

##### SVG definition

```py
import dash_svg as svg

svg.Svg(
    viewBox='0 0 55 55',
    children=svg.G(
        fill='white',
        children=[
            svg.Circle(cx=30, cy=30, r='25', strokeWidth=5, stroke='green'),
            svg.Circle(cx=40, cy=40, r='25', strokeWidth=5, stroke='green')]
    )
)
```

rendered as:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 55 55">
  <g fill="white">
    <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="25" stroke="green" stroke-width="5"></circle>
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="25" stroke="green" stroke-width="5"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

image:

[image: Two circles SVG]